# Wildfly 9 with infispan

Tags: java, infinispan, wildfly-9

I am trying to enable infinispan cache in `Wildfly 9`. I modified standalone-full.xml under:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:3.0">

<cache-container name="myCache" jndi-name="java:jboss/infinispan/container/myCache">
            <local-cache name="cachedb"/>
        </cache-container>
```

Started server using bellow command:

```
standalone --server-config=standalone-full.xml -b 0.0.0.0
```

And getting following error:

> Context initialization failed:    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.infinispan.manager.CacheContainer] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=java:jboss/infinispan/container/myCache, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}

Answer (score 1):

the `jndi-name` seems to be wrong. As shown [in this quickstart](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-quickstart/tree/master/jboss-as7), you need to update the configuration as follows:

```
<cache-container name="myCacheContainer" default-cache="myCache">
    <local-cache name="myCache"/>
</cache-container>
```

And use the following code snippet for injection:

```
@Resource(lookup="java:jboss/infinispan/container/myCacheContainer")
private static EmbeddedCacheManager container;
```

I see Spring in the stacktrace so probably you will need to do something similar there.